# Unable to retrive parent records which does not have any child records MySQL

Tags: mysql, dql

I have a table **District**(Parent table) and **college** (Child table) which are connected with **one-to-many**, one **District** may have multiple **Colleges**. Here **district_id** acts as a Foreign key in the **College** table. I am trying to retrieve districts which doesn't have any colleges associated with it using the below query but it doesn't give the correct results

```
select * from district where district_id not in (select district_id from college)
```

[image]

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: @scaisEdge done!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join  between distrct  and collegeand che for not matching key

```
select distinct d.* 
from district d
left join college c on c.district_id = d.district_id 
where c.district_id is null
```